# MySQL: Selecting from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT 
DISTINCT sites.site_id,
sites.site_name,
sites.site_url,
earnings.cust_id
FROM 
sites, 
earnings
WHERE sites.site_id = earnings.site_id AND sites.site_id IN('8', '1666')
```

That query gives me very well the information asked. It returns two rows, one for site 8 and another for site 1666, with the information on them from those tables.

Now, I want that the cust_id number be used to select from another table (let's say table customers) where they are stored by id and where other info is such as name, last name, etc.

Basically what I need is to expand that query to extract customer name and last name from the table customers, using the ids obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same way you got the info from two tables. Add a comma, add the third table name, and add the relationship to your WHERE clause like you did with the first two tables.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT sites.site_id,
sites.site_name,
sites.site_url,
earnings.cust_id,
customers.name,
customers.last_name
FROM 
sites, 
earnings,
customers
WHERE sites.site_id = earnings.site_id AND sites.site_id IN('8', '1666') AND customers.id = earnings.cust_id
```

I think it's clearer to write out the JOINs though:

```
SELECT
  sites.site_id,
  sites.site_name,
  sites.site_url,
  earnings.cust_id,
  customers.name,
  customers.last_name
FROM
  sites
INNER JOIN
  earnings
ON
  earnings.site_id = sites.site_id
INNER JOIN
  customers
ON
  customers.id = earnings.cust_id
WHERE
  sites.site_id IN (8, 1666)
GROUP BY
  sites.site_id
```

Comment: Yes, please please please use explicit joins.  It helps to document the relationships (among other things).  Working with implicit joins is a good way to accrue incorrect assumptions.

Comment: +1 for writing out joins (relationships) and not mixing them into the where (filters)